# how can manage hangup event in node js?

Tags: node.js

how can manage hangup event in node js ari client ?
I want to insert special data to databases before hanging up.

```
channel.hangup(function (err) {
                var currenttime = new Date();
                var post = currenttime.getYear()+'-'+currenttime.getMonth()+'-'+currenttime.getDay()+' '+currenttime.getHours()+':'+currenttime.getMinutes()+':'+currenttime.getSeconds();
                db.insert('UPDATE user_log SET endtime = ? WHERE users_id = ?',post,user_id,'');
                process.exit(0);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

i find it :)
when user hangs up call , client go to StatisEnd , we can write function for this state, and call it.

```
client.on('StasisEnd', [function name for example hangup]);

function hangup(){
  //code
}
```